# Transclude/Import one wordpress page to another

Tags: themes

I making a wordpress website with Divi as the theme.
I know there is a way in mediawiki to import one page into another, it is called transclusion, not sure how to do this in Wordpress - I see there is a plugin for it https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-pages/

Is there a native feature of wordpress which allows to do this (without plugin)?
How would it work with the Divi theme?

Comment: "Is there a native feature of wordpress which allows to do this (without plugin)?" (as far as I know) no. "How would it work with the Divi theme?" that is off topic here, sorry. You can ask in more Divi oriented / more general groups instead.

Answer (score 0):

The insert page plugin just works with Divi. There is an option called "Code" in that wp-markup for the insert page plugin just worked.